# Multiple requests to backend because of Pagination in Django Haystack

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, pagination, django-haystack

I am using Elasticsearch as my backend.

In one of my views, I do a filter like this:

```
SearchQuerySet().filter(...)
```

and it returns, let's say, 55 objects.

Then, I iterate over the results inside a for loop to perform some operation on every object.

The result is as expected. However, when I check the logs of elasticsearch, I see something like this:

```
[12:38:16,504] {"time":"2015-07-22T12:38:16.504+05:00","starttime":"2015-07-22T12:38:16.502+05:00","localaddr":"127.0.0.1","localport":9200,"remoteaddr":"127.0.0.1","remoteport":58718,"scheme":"http","method":"GET","path":"/haystack/modelresult/_search","querystr":"_source=true","code":200,"status":"OK","size":13633,"duration":2,"year":"2015","month":"07","day":"22","hour":"12","minute":"38","dow":"Wed","cluster":"elasticsearch_venta","data":"{\"query\": {\"filtered\": {\"filter\": {\"terms\": {\"django_ct\": [\"items.item\"]}}, \"query\": {\"match_all\": {}}}}, \"from\": 0, \"size\": 10}"}
[12:38:16,509] {"time":"2015-07-22T12:38:16.509+05:00","starttime":"2015-07-22T12:38:16.508+05:00","localaddr":"127.0.0.1","localport":9200,"remoteaddr":"127.0.0.1","remoteport":58718,"scheme":"http","method":"GET","path":"/haystack/modelresult/_search","querystr":"_source=true","code":200,"status":"OK","size":13719,"duration":1,"year":"2015","month":"07","day":"22","hour":"12","minute":"38","dow":"Wed","cluster":"elasticsearch_venta","data":"{\"query\": {\"filtered\": {\"filter\": {\"terms\": {\"django_ct\": [\"items.item\"]}}, \"query\": {\"match_all\": {}}}}, \"from\": 10, \"size\": 10}"}
[12:38:16,515] {"time":"2015-07-22T12:38:16.515+05:00","starttime":"2015-07-22T12:38:16.513+05:00","localaddr":"127.0.0.1","localport":9200,"remoteaddr":"127.0.0.1","remoteport":58718,"scheme":"http","method":"GET","path":"/haystack/modelresult/_search","querystr":"_source=true","code":200,"status":"OK","size":13429,"duration":2,"year":"2015","month":"07","day":"22","hour":"12","minute":"38","dow":"Wed","cluster":"elasticsearch_venta","data":"{\"query\": {\"filtered\": {\"filter\": {\"terms\": {\"django_ct\": [\"items.item\"]}}, \"query\": {\"match_all\": {}}}}, \"from\": 20, \"size\": 10}"}
```

That is, SearchQuerySet is returning 10 items every time.

I tried `load_all` but it did not help.

I think it is becuase SearchQuerySet returned a paginated results.

How can I reduce the number of requests to elasticsearch to one, i.e. get all items at once?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `results_per_page` to None in your SearchView. SearchView is defined as bellow in the official repo:

```
class SearchView(object):
    ...
    results_per_page = RESULTS_PER_PAGE
```

Comment: I am not doing a search. I am using SearchQuerySet() for filtering :(

Answer (score 0):

```
SearchQuerySet().filter(...).query.get_results()
```